# Variance of Binomial Distribution - formula

Tags: probability-theory, binomial-distribution, variance

This might be a really stupid question... but still here we go:

For the Variance we have two formulas:
(i)$$
\sigma^2:=\sum_{k=0}^n (k-\mu)^2p = \sum_{k=0}^n (k^2-2npk+n^2p^2)p= (\sum_{k=0}^n k^2- \sum_{k=0}^n2npk+\sum_{k=0}^n n^2p^2)p= \sum_{k=0}^nk^2p - 2np\sum_{k=0}^nkp +n^2p^2 = 
\sum_{k=0}^nk^2p - 2n^2p^2+n^2p^3
$$
with $\mu=np$ being the Expected Value and also (ii)
$$
Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 = \sum_{k=0}^nk^2p - (np)^2
$$
Now $n^2p^2+n^2p^3\neq (np)^2$ obviously, so where is my mistake?

Comment: You cannot use the parameter $p$ and the probability $P(X=k)$ interchangeably as you seem to be doing

Comment: Am I? I mean $Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 = \sum_{k=0}^nk^2p - (np)^2$ is definitly true, but the calculus for the above formula must be wrong somehow. Above I am not using $P(X=k)$ at all, just $p$.

Comment: That formula is not 'definitely true' it is false. You need to use $P(X=k)$ not $p$ in the definition $$E(f(X))=\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)P(X=k)$$ for a binomial distribution $X\sim B(n,p)$

Comment: Thank you for helping but... https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Binomial_Distribution#Proof_1distribution is this wrong then?

Comment: $(k-\mu)^2=k^2-2knp+(np)^2$.  You have $-(np)^2$ for the third term.  In the second expression you have $2np^2k$ which  should be $2npk$.  Check your algebra!

Comment: That link uses the correct definition. Did you even read it?

Comment: @PeterForeman yes of course. But is my definition wrong then? There must be a way to show it with my definition also.

Comment: @herbsteinberg thank you, I corrected that mistake. Still not getting how to get to the same result...

Comment: I added a further correction.  Your error led to the $p^3$ term.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I'm not sure where the mistake is with the $p^3$, it comes from multiplying $(np)^2$ with $p$ for the last term. Is that wrong?

Comment: The fundamental error lies in the first expression  It should be $\sum_{k=0}^n(k-\mu)^2p_k$ where $p_k=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$.  This is the result given in the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use that $B(n;p)$ is the sum of $n$ independent $B(1,p)$ random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct method to obtain the variance in both ways begins with either
$$\text{Var}(X)=E((X-\mu)^2)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left((k-np)^2\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\right)$$
or
$$\text{Var}(X)=E(X^2)-\mu^2=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(k^2\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\right)-(np)^2$$